# Regex to skip email/phone throws error for newline (enter key) - HTML/ AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex, angular-ngmodel

I want to check multiple line of strings to prevent user from entering emails and phone numbers and notify them the error message "ERR1"(eg, phone no and email are not allowed).

I used the following Regular Expression (RE):

```
$rootScope.RejectEmailPhoneNo='^(?:(?!(@|([0-9]{3}( |-|_|\.)[0-9]{3})|[0-9]{4}|([0-9]{2}( |-|_|\.)[0-9]{2})|([0-9]( |-|_|\.)[0-9]( |-|_|\.)[0-9]))).)+$'
```

**Desired Result:** RE should not allow multi-digit numbers (Eg, 4454, 313 345, 22 14,546-343, 1 2 2 4, etc) and '@' symbol. Allow any other character (using 'dot').

**Issue:** However, what happens is: when the user inputs *enter key*, they get notified of error message "ERR1".
When I altered the RE to allow newline using DotAll operator,I get the error message 'ERR1' even when I enter 'abcde'

```
$rootScope.RejectEmailPhoneNo='^(?:(?!(@|([0-9]{3}( |-|_|\.)[0-9]{3})|[0-9]{4}|([0-9]{2}( |-|_|\.)[0-9]{2})|([0-9]( |-|_|\.)[0-9]( |-|_|\.)[0-9])))[\s\S])+$'
```

When I used '(?s)' instead of [\s\S] - it allows all the characters including @ and multi-digit numbers.

My question is:

**(1) How would I make this regular expression to not throw error for newline - however must throw an error only when the user enters email (or atleast @) and multi-digit numbers?**

The above RE is used in the context:

```
     <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
     <label>Description</label>
     <textarea md-maxlength="900" rows="1" ng-model="job.description" ng-    required=true name="description" type="text"
     pattern={{RejectEmailPhoneNo}}
     ng-class="{ error : profile_form.description.$touched && profile_form.description.$error.required,typed : profile_form.description.$valid && profile_form.description.$touched && profile_form.description.$dirty }"
    class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength"
    aria-multiline="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>

    <div ng-messages="fulltime_form.description.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Please provide description.</div>
    <div ng-message="pattern">Phone numbers and emails are not allowed.</div>
```

** (2) If the RE can be checked for the 'Description' through a controller function - how do I write it as a function in angular-JS?**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood it right

> **Desired Result**: RE should not allow multi-digit numbers (Eg, 4454, 313 345, 22 14,546-343, 1 2 2 4, etc) and '@' symbol. Allow any other character (using 'dot').
>
> **Issue**: However, what happens is: when the user inputs enter key, they get notified of error message "ERR1". When I altered the RE to allow newline using DotAll operator,I get the error message 'ERR1' even when I enter 'abcde'

The problem is: **You need Search for the occurrence of an e-mail inside a string.**
If there is an e-mail, then **show the error**.

If this is your problem, then the solution is pretty simple, the code above should solve it:

```
const regex = /([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)/i;
const str = `hello,

this is an email test
i am verifying whether there is or not an email in this message

regards,
email@domain.com`;

let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if(m.length > 0){
        alert('there is email(s). Show the error');
    }
}else{
  alert('there is no email. Success!');
}
```

It alerts the error **only** if there is an e-mail address inside the text.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to give more context on the usage of the RE. The code is in angular format - and not sure how to fit in the JS code given by you.